# how to know the tree strucuture of a large xml file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml file with a relatively simple tree structure. However, there are some very long lists inside so that I can not find all the names of the child elements using my eyeballs. Is there a way to identify the tree structure for just first two or three layers of the file?

Comment: Use the DataSet ReadXML method.  The DataSet name is the root level.  the DataTable names are the 2nd level of tags.  The column names in the Datatables are the 3rd level of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it with Ie. you will be able then to colapse/expand groups so you will be able to better understand the tree.